# What am I doing wrong? The error message is not showing up

Tags: c#, javascript, html, regex

I have a multiline textbox in which I should not allow the user to enter any HREF links. 
So I am trying to string match using Regex as follows. 
But I am not getting the error message. What am I doing wrong?

```
Regex strMatch = new Regex(@"^(?:(?:<a )?href|</a>)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (strMatch.IsMatch(EmailTextBox.Text.Trim()))
 {
   vsumPage.AddErrorMessage("Cannot enter links");
 }
```

Also the same check needs to work in JS too. But it it giving me some exception. not sure what am i doing wrong. Here is my JS function

```
function doPreview()
 {
  var getEncodedStr = encode("<%=EmailTextBox.ClientID%>"); 
  var strInvalid = "Email instructions cannot have links included";
  var str = getEncodedStr.match(/@"(?:<a )?href|</a>"/) ;
  if (str == null)
  {
    var targetURL = 'Preview.aspx?txtName=' + getEncodedStr ;
    window.open(targetURL, null, "height=700,width=600,dependent=yes,hotkey=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no");
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
   alert(strInvalid);
  }
}
```

Here's the output that I am testing it with

```
Testing Testing <br/>
<b> Hello Testing </b> <br/>
<b> Testing 2000 character and link check </b> <br/>
<b> Hello </b> <a href="www.google.com">Click Me </a>
```

Updated again: 
Tried this one as given below:
But it always comes to the alert "Test3 0" part...even when an

```
          function doPreview()
      {
          var getEncodedStr = encode("<%=EmailTextBox.ClientID%>"); 
          var strInvalid = "Email instructions cannot have links included";
          var checkCount = "0" ;
          alert("Test 1" + checkCount);
          if(/<\/[\s\S]?a\b/gm.test(decode(getEncodedStr)))
          { 
            checkCount = "1" ;
            alert("Test 2" + checkCount);
            alert((/<\/?a\b/.test(decode(getEncodedStr))));
            return false;
          }
          if (checkCount == "0")
          {                  
            alert("Test 3" + checkCount);
            var targetURL = 'EPreview.aspx?txtName=' + getEncodedStr ;
            window.open(targetURL, null, "height=700,width=600,dependent=yes,hotkey=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no");
            return false;
          }
      }
```

Comment: What is the string you are trying this with? Right off the bat, it looks like I can have <a class="something" href="url"> and it'll accept it.

Comment: Why the close votes? Every other regex question on here is "how do I write a regex to detect blah blah blah". The response is always "what have you tried?". Ditty has actually told us what he tried, but apparently now it's "too localized"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^` asserts that this pattern occurs at the beginning of the string. Try removing it. Also you could probably change the pattern to:

```
@"</?a\b"
```

This will simply look for a `<a` or `</a` making sure that it is really an anchor tag, by using the word-boundary `\b` (which asserts that there is no letter or digit or underscore afterwards - but a space or `>` for example).

If that does not do it, it would really help to see your actual input.

Comment: Done. Can you please check and let me know what am I doing wrong? Also I need the same check in JS too. I am using the following but it is giving me some Exception on (

Comment: @Ditty please try my regex again, I had an extraneous `)` in there.

Comment: Yes this works. Thank you so much. How do i test it in JS? JS is giving some error as well.

Comment: @Ditty use the same pattern, but escape the slash: `/<\/?a\b/` and use it with `test` instead of `match`.

Comment: So should I check strMatch.test?

Comment: @Ditty `if(/<\/?a\b/.test(getEncodedStr)) { /* anchor encountered */ }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20528/discussion-between-ditty-and-m-buettner)

Comment: Not able to do in jfiddle.. Havent tried anytime and so not sure how to create it.

Comment: @Ditty [here is one that works](http://jsfiddle.net/exVtQ/). Try using more of your own code in this JSFiddle (click "Fork"). Then when you can reproduce your issue "Save" it and post the link

Comment: Yes. That works. But It is not stopping when I am doing it from my asp.net page. Not sure what the issue is. Maybe I should post it again as asp.net issue? But Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: @Ditty yes, if you cannot solve the problem, repost the new issue as an asp.net question, since it is beyond the scope of this one.

Comment: I think the issue is due to the input being in multiline. So do I need to add any m in the front? Also the input can also have the carriage return.

Comment: @Ditty that shouldn't make any difference. `m` only changes the behavior of `^` and `$` (which are not used) and line break characters only become an issue when `.` is used (which it is not).

Comment: I updated it again with an alert. please see above example. Can't understand why it is always coming to the Alert 3 part even when <a href code exists. Please help.

Comment: @Ditty what does `decode` do? Or rather, what does the output of `decode(getEncodedStr)` look like? Also, why the addition of `[\s\S]?`. And as I said none of the modifiers will make any difference.

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually my mistake. Instead of trying to access the value I was trying to get text ID name. So the textID name does not find the href link hence it never came into the other part. Once I updated the getEncodedStr to get the actual Value instead of the ID it worked fine. 

Thank you so much.